# Switching an ID with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to switch out an ID (and I know a class would be better but in this case I need to use an ID) for a product listing template. Unfortunately it only works on the first click. I am unable to switch back once done. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code I am using

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.toggle").bind("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var theid = $(this).attr("id");
        var thecontainer = $("div#container");

    if($(this).hasClass("active")) { 
        return false;
    } else {

        if(theid == "gridView") {
           $(this).addClass("active");
           $("#listView").removeClass("active");

        thecontainer.removeAttr('id');
        thecontainer.attr('id', 'container');
        }
        else if(theid == "listView") {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $("#gridView").removeClass("active");

            thecontainer.removeAttr('id');
            thecontainer.attr('id', 'containerList');

            } 
        }

    });
});
```

And here is the html for the links I am using to toggle the view.

```
  <div class="buttonPanel">
    <a id="gridView" class="btnGridView toggle active" href="#">Grid</a> 
    <a id="listView" class="btnListView toggle" href="#">List</a>   
  </div>
```

The CSS is pretty lengthy but in short there are two versions for a grid view with boxes and functions, and a straight list view.

Comment: Removing ID attribute wont do much beyond changing markup. You need to use `.prop()` to change the actual ID value of the DOM object.

Comment: theres nothing in that code that can switch the ids back to listview or gridview after they are changed.  so it should only work once as container and container list wont trigger the if statement in the else statement.

Comment: I've not used .prop() what would that look like?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your document.ready:
    `$("div#container").addClass("containerClass");`
NOT inside the click event.

Then replace `var thecontainer = $("div#container");`

with `var thecontainer = $(".containerClass");`